# How to use MySQL database connected through python in another computer?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I had to create a school management system in python for my school project.

I created a database in MySQL and connected it to my python program using `MySQL.connector`.

I was told to bring the program on a CD to school to show that it is working, but **I don't know how to copy the MySQL database to the CD** so as to get a working program in my school computer. It just shows an error that it can't connect to the given host.

PLEASE HELP FAST.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a dump of your MySQL database and copy the file generated (a dump) in your CD
**mysqldump** would be the command you can use

Here is how you can use the mysqldump utility

```
mysqldump -u [user name] –p [password] [options] [database_name] [tablename] > [dumpfilename.sql]
```

Then you can restore the database from the dump file in the other computer (in the school computer for your case). That way you can demonstrate running code

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Do mark upvote to the answer if it helps you complete your task